# Difference between na().drop() and filter(col.isNotNull) (Apache Spark)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any difference in semantics between `df.na().drop()` and `df.filter(df.col("onlyColumnInOneColumnDataFrame").isNotNull() && !df.col("onlyColumnInOneColumnDataFrame").isNaN())` where `df` is *Apache Spark* `Dataframe`?

Or shall I consider it as a bug if the first one does NOT return afterwards `null` (not a String null, but simply a `null` value) in the column `onlyColumnInOneColumnDataFrame` and the second one does?

EDIT: added `!isNaN()` as well. The `onlyColumnInOneColumnDataFrame` is the only column in the given `Dataframe`. Let's say it's type is `Integer`.

Comment: Could you provide an example data?

Comment: I've noticed those `null`s with the following code - https://gist.github.com/xjrk58/87dd094e2987ecc448db, but will try to simplify it and provide reproducible case with input data. To be more precise after calling `df.show()` on line 4, column "definitionId" contained `null` values.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

With `df.na.drop()` you drop the rows containing **any** null or NaN values.

With `df.filter(df.col("onlyColumnInOneColumnDataFrame").isNotNull())` you drop those rows which have null only in the column `onlyColumnInOneColumnDataFrame`.

If you would want to achieve the same thing, that would be `df.na.drop(["onlyColumnInOneColumnDataFrame"])`.

Comment: The point is that `onlyColumnInOnColumnDataFrame` is the only column in the given `DataFrame` and I've tried as well `isNotNaN()` (or maybe it was `!isNan()`), but still I'm getting null values in this column after filtering and the question is if it's a bug or I'm missing something.

Comment: As zero323 asked, please provide some example data.

Comment: Daniel, should the call be df.na.drop() and df.na.drop(subset=["onlyColumnInOneColumnDataFrame"])

Comment: Is this exclusive? i.e if both onlyColumnInOneColumnDataFrame" and another col is also null it would NOT be filtered. If that is the case then maybe you should have written: "
With df.filter(df.col("onlyColumnInOneColumnDataFrame").isNotNull()) you drop those rows which have null in the column onlyColumnInOneColumnDataFrame

Just curious being exclusive seems strange to me.

Comment: @DanielZolnai Could you explain why `df.na.drop(['ColName'])` won't work to drop rows containing null values in specific Column. I am getting this error error: `illegal start of simple expression null_df.drop.na(["Debit"]).show()`

Comment: With this code (using pyspark 2.4.4), I got the error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`. I needed to specify the `subset` param name: `df.na.drop(subset=["column_name"])`

Answer (score 1):

In one case, I had to select records with NAs or nulls or >=0. I could so by using only coalesce function and none of like above 3 functions.

```
rdd.filter("coalesce(index_column, 1000) >= 0")
```