# Drop null value column in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning

i am having below given code

```
ataset.select("Lead Owner").show();
        dataset.filter(dataset.col("Lead Owner").isNotNull());
        dataset.select("Lead Owner").show();
```

But it is not removing rows which has null value for column Lead Owner. Can  anyone tell what wrong i am doing here ?

Comment: Is this Null is a Null that you add or is a Null from Spark? Like Left Join that create a Null field?

Comment: this is Null from spark, and i am trying to do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35478464/3572733

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datasets are Immutable. `dataset.filter` is a transformation and will return a new dataset, rather than modifying the original. Please refer to the [DataSet Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html)

```
val filteredData = dataset.filter(dataset.col("Lead Owner").isNotNull());
filteredData.select("Lead Owner").show();
```