# count items of structure python

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Using python and pyspark I'm creating a new dataframe of struct. How can i test if this structure has no nested fields and if it has none then delete them?

In the code below there are two structure color and Time. I want to test if one of those is NULL then delete it.
**Code**

df1 = sqlCtx.createDataFrame([Row(Row(5, 9, Row(12)), Row(2,True))], schema)

```
df = df1.withColumn("data",
           struct(
               struct(
               struct(struct(lit(2).alias("b3711"),
                    lit(2).alias("b3712")).alias("b371"),
            (when(col("x2.field3").cast(IntegerType())== lit(1),
            struct(struct(col("x1.field1").alias("dark"),).alias('Black')
               ,col("x1.field1").alias("cl"))).alias("Color")),

                      (when(col("x2.field3").cast(IntegerType())== lit(2),
                struct(col("x1.field1").alias("Q1"),
                col("x1.field1").alias("T1"))).alias("Times"))


                     ).alias("b37")).alias("b3")
                )).drop('x1','x2')

     <DATA>
           <T1>Numerical</T1>
                    <IT>Y</IT>
                    <color>
                       <black>v</black>
                    </color>
                    <Time/>
     </DATA>
```

I was thinking about countng items in color and time. I did the line below but it is not what i want. Who have an idea

```
 count(data.T1.Time)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It would be helpful to know what you have tried to do to solve your problem and what error messages you've received when your attempts didn't work.

Comment: thank you so much :) @DaveL17 i tried  ** if ((data.T1.Time).isNotNull):
    print('1')**

Comment: if ((data.T1.Time).isNull): print('1')  . In the two lines of code it does the print.

Answer (score 0):

With the `dropna` function you can filter, remove and create a new DataFrame without null values. Please refer the documentation for further information but basically, you can specify how you filter and drop the null values (ie: all columns, any of the columns or a subset of columns). In your case, you should drop any of the columns that has null values, which results in a following code:

```
print(dataDF.count())
print(dataDF.dropna("any").count())
```

Update: To check only for null values in Time and color you can filter for subset:

```
newDF = dataDF.dropna("any", subset=["Color", "Time"])
```

Documentation link: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reponse. But i forget to notice that my data can contains other structs . Is there a manner to do the check only for Time and color.??

Comment: @mail Thanks for your comment! See my update answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your disponibility . I had a problem, i want to create struct (color or Time ) based on the value of **x2.field3**. When i executed my code i noticed that if have the two struct created and one of the two was filled like mentionned in my test. The idea that i got is to delete the empty one .

Comment: in your test does not delete the hole struct because it appears again when i tap **df.printShema()** If you have any suggestions don't hesitate . thank you again :D

Comment: @mail Yes, the idea of drop is to delete the rows with null values in some columns, if you want to delete the whole column when having null values, please refer to the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629781/drop-if-all-entries-in-a-spark-dataframes-specific-column-is-null

Comment: Thank you @Mitodina but got the same thing .. **code** import pyspark.sql.functions as func
nonNull_cols = [c for c in df.columns if df.filter(func.col(c).isNotNull()).count() > 0]
new_df = df.select(*nonNull_cols)
new_df.printSchema()