# Remove null columns from a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, data-cleaning

I have a very dirty csv where there are several columns with only null values.

I would like to remove them. I am trying to select all columns where the count of null values in the column is not equal to the number of rows.

`clean_df = bucketed_df.select([c for c in bucketed_df.columns if count(when(isnull(c), c)) not bucketed_df.count()])`

However, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-2213215314329625>", line 1
    clean_df = bucketed_df.select([c for c in bucketed_df.columns if count(when(isnull(c), c)) not bucketed_df.count()])
                                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If anyone could help me get rid of these dirty columns, that would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop if all entries in a spark dataframe's specific column is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629781/drop-if-all-entries-in-a-spark-dataframes-specific-column-is-null) You can simply do a normal count and check which columns return 0.

Comment: Actually it does, but it's really slow. It takes about 10 minutes to run just one. Not viable because I need to do this multiple times on many datasets.

Comment: I don't think you can find a solution that is faster than a single count but it could be there is something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have very little experience with pyspark but it might not be a bad idea to create a dataframe with the counts and convert it to `pandas` since the counts dataframe will have a single row:

Starting from a dataframe which looks like below and saved as `null_df`

```
+---+---+---+----+
|  A|  B|  C|   D|
+---+---+---+----+
|  1|  a|  b|null|
|  2|  c|  d|null|
|  3|  e|  f|null|
+---+---+---+----+
```

---

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

counts = null_df.select([F.count(i).alias(i) for i in null_df.columns]).toPandas()
output = null_df.select(*counts.columns[counts.ne(0).iloc[0]])
```

Or even converting the entire first row to a dictionary and then loop over the dictionary

```
counts1 = null_df.select([F.count(i).alias(i) for i in null_df.columns])
output2 = null_df.select([k for k,v in counts1.first().asDict().items() if v >0])
```

which gives the below:

```
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  a|  b|
|  2|  c|  d|
|  3|  e|  f|
+---+---+---+
```

benchmarks as tested in my system:

```
%%timeit
counts = null_df.select([F.count(i).alias(i) for i in null_df.columns]).toPandas()
output = null_df.select(*counts.columns[counts.ne(0).iloc[0]])
#8.73 s ± 412 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
counts1 = null_df.select([F.count(i).alias(i) for i in null_df.columns])
output2 = null_df.select([k for k,v in counts1.first().asDict().items() if v >0])
#9.43 s ± 253 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
counts1 = null_df.select([F.count(i).alias(i) for i in null_df.columns])
output1 = null_df.select([c for c in counts1.columns if counts1[[c]].first()[c] > 0])
#35.3 s ± 1 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve this problem,

1) Write a UDF function to add a column where the column's value is 1 if the required column(column that you're checking for NULL) value is NULL , then take a sum of the column , if the sum is equal to the row count , then drop the column

2) Use amazon spark dq library (A open source data quality library for spark) , the library has functions to profile your data , one of the column that the dq returns is the completeness factor for each column , If the completeness factor is 1 then the entire column values are NULL , you can remove those column 
I personally feel this option is great because it is meant to perform data quality checks using spark

there are lots of example in the below links

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/test-data-quality-at-scale-with-deequ/
https://github.com/awslabs/deequ

Answer (score 0):

Function "min" can be used, and columns with null values can be removed. Here on Scala, can be translated to Python easily:

```
// data sample
val df = Seq(("Bug", null.asInstanceOf[Integer], null.asInstanceOf[String]),
  ("Termit", null.asInstanceOf[Integer], null.asInstanceOf[String]))
  .toDF("name", "size", "type")
val fieldNames = df.schema.fieldNames

// get null values 
val fieldExpressions = fieldNames.map(c => min(c).alias(c))
val firstRow = df.select(fieldExpressions: _*).collect().head

val fieldsToDrop = fieldNames.filter(f => firstRow.isNullAt(fieldNames.indexOf(f)))
```