# AWS Glue PySpark can't count the records

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm using AWS Glue to extract data from EC2 (Postgre) to be transformed and put it on S3 when I tried to extract 1 table. I got an error looks like this:

[image]

Is there anything I can do? I tried to drop null fields or fillna, but none of those works.

UPDATE: I even selected a string-type column but still got the same error:
[image]

Comment: cause problem is described by last line in your screenshot (NaN for bigdecimal)

Comment: yes, but I can't figure out which column the error refers to, even if I select a string-type column, it still produces the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try, `df.isnull().any()` or `df.isnull().sum()`. This should help us see the columns with invalid NaN data. Also please try to fetch count of records with `df.count(dropna = False)` / `df.na.drop()`.  Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477472/difference-between-na-drop-and-filtercol-isnotnull-apache-spark), where its explained more in detail on handling null column data.

Hope this helps.