# sparksql get previous not null value in a column

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get the previous row value of a column only when it's not null in spark SQL.
since ignore nulls is not available the alternative would be rank and get a max of the value.

```
lag( val ignore nulls) over ()
```

```
SELECT id, val, val_partition, MAX(val) over (partition by val_partition)
FROM (
        SELECT
            id,
            val,
            sum(case when val is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id rows unbounded preceding) as val_partition
          FROM base
     )
```

I am trying to find if there is any other optimized way?

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477472/difference-between-na-drop-and-filtercol-isnotnull-apache-spark

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is fine, but can be written more concisely as:

```
SELECT id, val, val_partition,
       MAX(val) over (PARTITION BY grp)
FROM (SELECT b.*,
             COUNT(val) over (ORDER BY id) as grp
      FROM base b
     ) b;
```

Note as well that the windowing clause is not needed if `id` is unique.