# How to delete null values when saving json file to dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to save json file to a datagram, and I need to include only those values in a column which are not null. 
There is only one column in a file. 
I tried 
`.option("column", isNotNull)`
`.filter("column" is notNul)`
`.dropna("column")` 
but nothing works.
and I can't find any documentation on removing nulls when reading a json file.

Could anyone help me to resolve this, please? Thanks!

Comment: Add explanation of what the datagram is, also specify the language you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I mean 'dataframe', not datagram. And the language is python.

Comment: You can read the JSON and then filter the Pyspark DataFrame using `isNotNull()`, but it is a method which applies to a column. In your filter `"column"` is a String and `notNull` is  not a function: `df.filter(df.column_name.isNotNull())`. Please, check the documentation -> http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=filter#pyspark.sql.Column.isNotNull

Comment: @Amanda thanks for the answer. I tried this out: first I read the json file and then filtred null values like df.filter(df.column_name.isNotNull()).collect() and still null values appear in the column. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe original Nulls are not being interpreted as Null, maybe they are strings ¿?. It is possible to check with `df.where(df.column_name == "Null").limit(10).show()` (or the string showed as Null). If this returns some rows, then they are strings.

Comment: @Amanda, I resolved this with     `df = df.na.drop(how='any')` and it worked for me.

Comment: @Nadzeya, it means that your `Null`s are not actually `Null`s but `NaN`s (Not a Number). Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477472/difference-between-na-drop-and-filtercol-isnotnull-apache-spark